# How set order by clause in HQL by run time?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is there any way to set order by clause in `HQL` by run time. i.e. `select obj from Example1 order by <Here my column name and asc or desc` these two thing want to set in run time>.

Any proper solution...? I have try with adding two ? but it's not working. By replacing with string it could work....But is there any other way from `HQL`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to concatenate the appropriate field. If you don't like it, use [the Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria), which is designed to generate queries dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is Criteria API: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

e.g.:

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
 .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Iz%") )
 .add( Restrictions.gt( "weight", new Float(minWeight) ) )
 .addOrder( Order.asc("age") )
 .list();
```